# Выровнять таблицу внутри таблицы HTML?!

Tags: css3, html, css

есть у меня такая верстка (даже не спаршивайте зачем? поверьте жизненно важно))

```
<table border="1">
<tr>
<td>
  <div>
   <ul>
    <li><table border="1"><tr><td>текст</td></tr><tr><td>другой текст</td></tr></table></li>
    </ul>
  </div>
</td>
</tr>
</table>
```

и мне надо что бы таблица которая находится в списке и ячейке была по центру родительской таблицы как лучше сделать скажите??

Comment: зачем таблицу помещать в див, да еще и в ul li. имхо бред!!! в p и span засуньте ее! сори, злой с утра чето...

Comment: уж если такая пьянка то можно и <center></center> сделать, только доктайп уберите ;)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`<table align="center">` пробовали?